# How to run existing jupyter notebook that imports custom python module(both files are same level in repository folder) using google colab?

Tags: python, github, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I got a github repository having a ***program.py*** containing my python program and a ***notebook.ipynb***.

In the notebook, i import ***program*** and call its functions. This works normally as i run the ***notebook*** locally.

On Colab, i can open the ***notebook*** easily but every time i push changes to my repo i have to delete and restart the Colab runtime, reclone repo to it in order to run the new code right.
Is there any way to make this process less complicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly fetch the updated code for `program.py` by using `wget` to get the URL for the raw code, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67327780/8508004). That should eliminate the need for recloning.

And then to get the new versions produced by that code into your active namespace, without need for restarting the kernel, use `reload` from `importlib` to reload the functions in `program.py`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11724154/8508004) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22073792/8508004) and [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/how-to-work-with-pure-python-file-py/4443/6?u=fomightez) for options. Plus, [there is an autoreload magic for when you work in a Juptyer notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56729409/8508004). The pure Python I referenced first will work in the notebook, too. The pure Python versions are just less convenient.